# bash bind to command cuts the command unexpectedly

Tags: bash, bind

In my `.bashrc`, I've tried to use the following:

```
bind '"PP": "</dev/tty"'
```

However, when I write `PP` in my shell, only `</de` appears.

The command I wish to bind is not just `</dev/tty`, but  this simplifies the question so it is easier to reproduce

**UPDATE:**

It seems that my `v` key wasn't working anymore in my ssh session, It is quite strange and I don't know why. Restarting the ssh session made it work

Comment: You might be overflowing some buffer for `bind`.  It would be useful to see the the exact command.

Comment: It seems that my `v` key wasn't working anymore in my ssh session, It is quite strange and I don't know why. Restarting the ssh session made it work

Comment: Platform, bash version and full command would be useful. `</dev/tty` example works just fine here.